# QueryDSL subquery not working

Tags: java, mysql, querydsl

I'm trying to recreate the following SQL query in QueryDSL. The following is my SQL query which is currently working as inteded.

```
SELECT * FROM room x WHERE unit_id = (SELECT unit_id FROM room WHERE unit_id = x.unit_id GROUP BY unit_id HAVING(SUM(sqft) > 0))
```

I'm trying to write a QueryDSL query that does the same thing but honestly can't come any further than the bottom query.

```
JPASubQuery subQuery = new JPASubQuery();
subQuery.from(qRoom).groupBy(qRoom.unit).having(qRoom.sqft.sum().goe(0));

JPAQuery unitquery = from(qRoom)
   .where(qRoom.building.eq(building)).where(qRoom.unit.eq(subQuery));

return unitquery.list(qRoom);
```

The above query isn't working and i'm having trouble using subqueries in QueryDSL. What should I add/change to make this query working?

Comment: Are you encountering any error messages or how do you know that it's not working?

Comment: @jojonas my subquery isn't returning a unit object, also, I don't know how to use the unit from my 'main' query as the unit for my subquery.

Comment: you are using JPA? which persistence framework?

Comment: and you want to create a native (sql) query?

Comment: @Meiko No i want the JPAQuery to do the same as the shown SQL query but I don't know how exactly

Comment: could you try to log the generated Query of your persistence framework, maybe the HQL?

Comment: I might not have been clear enough in my post. The 2 big issues I have with the JPAQuery right now are 1. I don't know how to use the unit from the main query in my subquery so like in the SQL query: WHERE unit_id = x.unit_id and 2. I don't know how to return a 'unit' from the subquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it.

I just needed to change `.where(qRoom.unit.eq(subQuery));` too `.where(qRoom.unit.in(subQuery.list(qRuimte.unit)));`